# При выборе элемента из списка не показывается первый элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два селекта:

1. *selectMonth*,
2. *selectDay*.

При клике на первый выбираю месяц и, в соответствии с выбранным месяцем, во втором столбце подгружается количество дней в этом месяце, но дело в том, что при первом клике первый день не показывается у любого месяца, при повторном клике появляется, помогите поправить.

```js
function setMonth() {
  var month = [
    "январь", "февраль", "март",
    "апрель", "май", "июнь",
    "июль", "август", "сентябрь",
    "октябрь", "ноябрь", "декабрь"
  ];
  $.each(month, function(idx, el) {
    idx++
    $("#selectMonth").append("<option value=" + idx + ">" + el + "</option>")
  })
}

function setDays(month) {
  var date = new Date(2016, month, 0).getDate();
  $("#selectDay").find("option").remove();
  // setTimeout(function(){},100)
  for (i = 1; i <= date; i++) {
    $("#selectDay").append("<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>")
    console.log(i)
  }
}

var cnt = 0;
$(document).on("change", "#selectMonth", function() {
  month = $(this).val();
  setDays(month);
  if (cnt == 0) { //если выбрали месяц единожды удаляем Выберите месяц и Выберите день
    $("#selectMonth,#selectDay").find("option:eq(0)").remove();
  }
  cnt++
})


setMonth();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events">
  <select name="" id="selectMonth">
    <option>Выберите месяц</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="selectDay">
    <option>Выберите день</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[Пример на JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhz8nrmj/)

Comment: так Вы же сами удаляете первый элемент в каждом списке после добавления дней на первое изменение месяца: `$("#selectMonth,#selectDay").find("option:eq(0)").remove();`. Уберите отсюда `#selectDay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что удаление элементов из второго списка происходит в двух местах.

В функции *setDays* - удаляются **все** элементы, и добавляются нужные для выбранного месяца.

В функции обработчике события change - при первом срабатывании удаляются первые элементы в обоих списках.

Таким образом для решения достаточно либо перенести вызов *setDays* после проверки

```
var cnt = 0;
$(document).on("change", "#selectMonth", function() {
  month = $(this).val();
  if (cnt == 0) { //если выбрали месяц единожды удаляем Выберите месяц и Выберите день
    $("#selectMonth,#selectDay").find("option:eq(0)").remove();
  }
  cnt++
  setDays(month);
})
```

Либо не удалять первый элемент в списке дней, так как они и так удаляются до этого в функции *setDays*

```
$("#selectMonth").find("option:eq(0)").remove();
```

Пример

```js
function setMonth() {
  var month = [
    "январь", "февраль", "март",
    "апрель", "май", "июнь",
    "июль", "август", "сентябрь",
    "октябрь", "ноябрь", "декабрь"
  ];
  $.each(month, function(idx, el) {
    idx++
    $("#selectMonth").append("<option value=" + idx + ">" + el + "</option>")
  })
}

function setDays(month) {
  var date = new Date(2016, month, 0).getDate();
  $("#selectDay").find("option").remove();
  // setTimeout(function(){},100)
  for (i = 1; i <= date; i++) {
    $("#selectDay").append("<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>")
    console.log(i)
  }
}

var cnt = 0;
$(document).on("change", "#selectMonth", function() {
  month = $(this).val();
  if (cnt == 0) { //если выбрали месяц единожды удаляем Выберите месяц и Выберите день
    $("#selectMonth,#selectDay").find("option:eq(0)").remove();
  }
  cnt++
  setDays(month);
})


setMonth();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events">
  <select name="" id="selectMonth">
    <option>Выберите месяц</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="selectDay">
    <option>Выберите день</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

<sub>так же можно немного доработать код используя больше возможностей javascript и jquery</sub>

```js
function setMonth() {
  var months = [
    "январь", "февраль", "март",
    "апрель", "май", "июнь",
    "июль", "август", "сентябрь",
    "октябрь", "ноябрь", "декабрь"
  ];
  months.reduce(function(selectMonth, month, index) {
    return selectMonth.append($('<option>').val(index + 1).text(month));
  }, $("#selectMonth"));
}

function setDays(month) {
  var date = new Date(2016, month, 0).getDate();
  var selectDay = $("#selectDay");
  selectDay.empty();

  for (i = 1; i <= date; i++) {
    selectDay.append($('<option>').val(i).text(i));
  }
}


$(document).on("change", "#selectMonth", function selectMonthHandler() {

  $("#selectMonth option:first-child").remove();

  $(document).off('change', "#selectMonth", selectMonthHandler)
    .on('change', "#selectMonth", function() {
      setDays(this.value);
    });
  $(this).change();
})


setMonth();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events">
  <select name="" id="selectMonth">
    <option>Выберите месяц</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="selectDay">
    <option>Выберите день</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

минифицированный вариант с возможностью сохранения выбора дня при смене месяца, если такой даты в месяце нет, выбирается ближайшая к прежнему выбору.(последний день месяца)

```js
    function c(a) {
      return $.map(a, function(a, b) {
        ++b;
        return "<option value=" + b + ">" + (a || b) + "</option>"
      })
    }
    var d = $("#selectMonth"),
      f = $("option", d),
      e = $("#selectDay");
    d.append(c([
      "январь", "февраль", "март",
      "апрель", "май", "июнь",
      "июль", "август", "сентябрь",
      "октябрь", "ноябрь", "декабрь"
    ])).on({
      change: function() {
        f.remove();
        var a = (new Date(2016, this.value, 0)).getDate(),
          b = +e[0].value || 1;
        e[0].options.length = 0;
        e.append(c(Array(a)))
        e[0].value = b <= a ? b : a
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events">
  <select name="" id="selectMonth">
    <option>Выберите месяц</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="selectDay">
    <option>Выберите день</option>
  </select>
</div>
```